# Extracting value of checkbox generated dynamically through flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

Is there a way to read through an HTML page and return the value of the dynamic checkboxes which are clicked?

Now, I know how to get values from static check boxes even without using JS but since I am generating the below check boxes using data from Database I am not sure how to pin point each one and know which one the user checked,

When I went through developer tools in chrome I can see that the value of the generated check boxes changes but when I refer to them it still does not work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

 <form action="/test" method="post">
  <button type="submit" id="exporst-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Import Test Data <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-import"></span></button>
  <br>
   <br>
     <div id="table">
        <table class="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Selection</th>
                <th>Slno</th>
                <th>Region</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

    <tbody>
    {% for obj in TD %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="chb[]"  > {{obj.OEHR_Mtest_Slno}}
                </td>
            <td>
                {{obj.OEHR_Mtest_Slno}}
                </td>
            <td>
                {{obj.OEHR_Mtest_SF_Part_Number}}
            </td>

        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>

</table>
</div>

  </div>

        <!--<p id="export" name="test"></p>-->
        <input type="hidden" id="exp" name="test">
<button type="submit" id="export-btn" class="btn btn-success">Execute <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></button>

</form>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
   $('#export-btn').click(function () {
       alert($('#mytable').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length + '      checked');
    });
 </script>


</html>
```

I can use the above JS to know how many checkboxes have been checked, I want to know the value of the ones checked and I am not able to get that.

Comment: What do you mean the value? The name? Which row it's on?

Comment: @M.Davis  This one {{obj.OEHR_Mtest_Slno}} from the server next to checkbox

Comment: Probably renders the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're dynamically generating the checkboxes, it's helpful to also dynamically generate the values for the checkboxes. That way, when you `POST` the request via the submit button, Flask can determine which checkboxes were checked by reading the values. I would change your HTML to:

```
{% for obj in TD %}
    <tr>
        <td>
            {# Assuming obj.OEHR_Mtest_Slno is a unique value #}
            <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" value="{{obj.OEHR_Mtest_Slno}}"> {{obj.OEHR_Mtest_Slno}}
            </td>
        <td>
            {{obj.OEHR_Mtest_Slno}}
            </td>
        <td>
            {{obj.OEHR_Mtest_SF_Part_Number}}
        </td>

    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Then in your backend, you can access the values via:

```
# Use .getlist if you are using HTML form elements with the same name
chkbox_values = request.form.getlist('chkbox')  # returns a list of values that were checked
```

Comment: This actually worked! Nice idea to introduce the {{DB value}} in the checkbox value, I was wondering why it didn't work since on rendering it generated its own value sequentially, So I was trying to somehow get that, Smart move.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken,

```
var foo = $('#mytable').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
```

will return an array of html elements which are checkboxes, and are checked. You can then do:

```
var bar = [];
foo.each(function (index) {
    var baz = this.parentNode.textContent || this.parentNode.innerText;
    if (baz && baz.length > 0)
        bar.push(baz);
});
console.log(bar);
```

That will make `bar` an array of the values which were checked. It gets the checkboxes which were checked, finds their parents (`<td>` tags), and gets the text inside (which skips the `<input>` tags). This will do it client-side.